# Nginx : to show an error page for all the paths excluding a few , for 400 status code

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I have a requirement for pattern matching in url which excludes some files and show an error page on getting an error code 400

Eg: I have URL `/test/v1/` and `/test/v2/`. I need to show a custom error page (for status 400) for all `/test/x` where `x` can be anything, except `/test/v1/` and `/test/v2/`.

so what should be my regular expression in location directive in nginx.conf file i tried below but failed.

```
location ~* /test(?!\/(v1|v2)) {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}

error_page  400 /400.html;
```

Comment: How did that fail? You mean `/test/v1/more/` should be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\/test\/(v1|v2)\/?
```

It allows `/test/v1/` and `/test/v2/` (without final slash works as well).
It fails when `/test/nope/` or `/nope`.

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c9OU81/1)

Answer (score 0):

Allow test/(v1|v2)/, and disable all the rest:

```
location ~* /test(\/(v1|v2)\/) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    break;
}


location / {
     return 400 "bad request";
}
```